# Force Output of Powershell Script in Tabular Form

Tags: powershell

Is there anyway to force the output of a PowerShell v3 script in to tabular form?  My script is outputting a list of services in linear form even though there are only 6 fields in the output object (get-process outputs 8 fields in tabular form).  Here is my code:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Gets a list of services on a given computer that are supposed to automatically start but are not currently running.
.PARAMETER ComputerName
The computer name(s) to retrieve the info from.
.PARAMETER IgnoreList
The path and filename of a text file containing a list of service names to ignore.  This file has to list actual service names and not display names.  Defaults to "StoppedServices-Ignore.txt" in the current directory.
.PARAMETER StartServices
Optional switch that when specified will cause this function to attempt to start all of the services it finds stopped.
.EXAMPLE
Get-StoppedServices -ComputerName Computer01 -IgnoreList '.\IgnoredServices.txt' -StartServices
.EXAMPLE
Get-StoppedServices –ComputerName Computer01,Computer02,Computer03
.EXAMPLE
"Computer01" | Get-StoppedServices
.EXAMPLE
Get-StoppedServices –ComputerName (Get-Content ComputerList.txt)
.EXAMPLE
Get-Content ComputerList.txt | Get-StoppedServices -IgnoreList '.\IgnoredServices.txt' -StartServices
#>
Function Get-StoppedServices {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] [String[]]$ComputerName,
    [string]$IgnoreList,
    [switch]$StartServices
  )
  PROCESS {
    # Load the list of services to ignore (if specified).
    if ($IgnoreList) {
      if (Test-Path $IgnoreList) {
        $ignore = import-csv -header Service $IgnoreList
        Write-Verbose "Ignoring the following services:"
        Write-Verbose $ignore.ToString()
      } else {
        Write-Warning "Could not find ignore list $IgnoreList."
      }
    }

    # Get a list of stopped services that are set to run automatically (ie: that should be running)
    foreach ($c in $ComputerName) {
      Write-Verbose "Getting services from $($c.Name)"
      if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $c -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Try {
          $serv += get-wmiobject -query "Select __Server,Name,DisplayName,State,StartMode,ExitCode,Status FROM Win32_Service WHERE StartMode='Auto' AND State!='Running'" -computername $c -erroraction stop
        } catch {
          Write-Warning "Could not get service list from $($c)"
        }
      }
    }

    # Create the resulting list of services by removing any that are in the ignore list.
    $results = @()
    foreach ($s in $serv) {
      Write-Verbose "Checking if $($s.name) in ignore list."
      if ($ignore -match $s.name) { 
        Write-Verbose "  *Service in ignore list."
      } else {
        Write-Verbose "  Service OK."
        $obj = New-Object -typename PSObject
        $obj | Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -name ComputerName -value ($s.PSComputerName) -passthru |
               Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -name ServiceName  -value ($s.Name)           -passthru |
               Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -name DisplayName  -value ($s.DisplayName)    -passthru |
               Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -name Status       -value ($s.Status)         -passthru |
               Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -name State        -value ($s.State)          -passthru |
               Add-Member -membertype NoteProperty -name ExitCode     -value ($s.ExitCode)
        $results += $obj
      }
    }

    # Try and start each of the stopped services that hasn't been ignored.
    if ($StartServices) {
      foreach ($s in $results) {
        Write-Verbose "Starting '$($s.DisplayName)' ($($s.name)) on '$($s.ComputerName)..."
        Try {
          Get-Service -Name $s.name -ComputerName $s.ComputerName -erroraction stop | Start-service -erroraction stop
        } Catch {
          Write-Warning "Could not start service $($s.name) on $($s.ComputerName)."
        }
      }  
    }

    # Output the list of filtered services to the pipeline.
    write-output $results
  }
}
```

Comment: That is certainly an interesting way to get a list of services

Comment: Try piping your output to `Format-Table`??  Powershell typically outputs data as objects and the results from `Get-Service` are no different.  You can always pipe an object to `Select *` to get all properties...  I'm really not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but hope this helps.  Usually with powershell if it seems hard, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @JimB - It's kind of a small project to learn Powershell scripting.  I wanted a quick way to find any services running on any of my servers that are stopped that should be running.  I want a report of these and I want it to try and automatically start them.  Maybe not the most elegant way to do it I grant you but like I said, it's a start.

Comment: @Colyn1337: I realize I could just pipe it to Format-Table but I guess I am just wondering why Powershell has chosen to, by default, not do that automatically?  Most of the output I see from Powershell commands comes out in tabular format so I thought that maybe there was something I needed to include in my function (or the synopsis) to make mine do it as well.

Comment: See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419,  https://vimeo.com/13395119 to learn powershell and best practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When one or more objects bubble up to the host, PowerShell looks at the number of properties the object has.

If an object's type can be resolved to a corresponding `Format.ps1xml` file (we'll get back to this in a minute), the formatting convention described in that document will be used - otherwise, it depends on the number of properties an object have.

---

If an object has less than 5 properties, it defaults to use `Format-Table` for output formatting:

```
PS C:\> New-Object psobject -Property ([ordered]@{PropA=1;PropB=2;PropC=3;PropD=4})

PropA PropB PropC PropD
----- ----- ----- -----
    1     2     3     4
```

If an object has *more* properties, it defaults to `Format-List` (which is what you experience):

```
PS C:\> New-Object psobject -Property ([ordered]@{PropA=1;PropB=2;PropC=3;PropD=4;PropE=5})


PropA : 1
PropB : 2
PropC : 3
PropD : 4
PropE : 5
```

---

Now, the reason that the objects returned from the `Get-Service` or `Get-Process` cmdlet seem to format into a nice, contextually relevant, more-than-5-column table, is that PowerShell was able to find a type-specific formatting document for that them.

These formatting files are all located in the PowerShell installation directory, you can locate the default ones with:

```
Get-ChildItem $PSHome *.Format.ps1xml
```

See `Get-Help about_Format.ps1xml` if you want to create your own format files.

---

The way PowerShell establishes a link between an object's type and the defined formatting views is by inspecting the hidden `pstypenames` property:

```
PS C:\> $obj.pstypenames
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
System.Object
```

PowerShell simply drills through this ancestral list of types to see if it has a corresponding formatting view for said type.

This means that you can trick PowerShell into formatting an object as if it were of another type, without actually meddling with the underlying .NET type system.

To show this, let's create a faux service controller - an object that kinda looks like something `Get-Service` could have returned, but really isn't:

```
PS C:\> $FauxService = New-Object psobject -Property @{
>>>   "Name"        = "FakeService3000"
>>>   "Status"      = "Faking"
>>>   "DisplayName" = "TrustworthyService"
>>>   "TrueName"    = "Really a fake"
>>>   "Author"="Clever Genius"
>>> }
PS C:\> $FauxService


Status      : Faking
Name        : FakeService3000
Author      : Clever Genius
DisplayName : TrustworthyService
TrueName    : Really a fake
```

As described above, PowerShell shows the output of `Format-List` since our `psobject` has 5 properties.

Now, let's try to inject a type name:

```
PS C:\> $FauxService.pstypenames.Insert(0,"System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController")
PS C:\> $FauxService

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Faking   FakeService3000    TrustworthyService
```

Voila!

Comment: Awesome explanation!  Just what I was looking for, thanks!